# Marker's shape - clickable area

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to use Google Maps Markers with circle icons. My problem is that the clickable area is a square instead of a circle.

I've tried to use Marker Shape as defined in the documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#MarkerShape
As I was able to read here, you can alter the clickable area of a marker. So, I did this:

```
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.023578942,15.368335626 ),
          zoom: 8
        });

        m1 = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(47.023578942,15.368335626 ),
          map: map,
          icon: {
            path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
            scale: 10,
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            fillOpacity: 1
          },
          shape: {coords: [0,0,50,50], type: "rect"}
        });
        m2 = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(47.523578942,15.368335626 ),
          map: map,
          icon: {
            path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
            scale: 10,
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            fillOpacity: 1
          },
          shape: {coords: [0,0,500], type: "circle"}
        });
```

Demo with the code: https://jsfiddle.net/6sm32nqc/1/

I've expected the clickable area to be a circle for one of the markers (the top one), but nothing is changed. The same 46x46 square clickable area is drawn (see darker area in the picture below):

[image: Highlighted clickable area]

I'm not sure what I'm missing here :(.

Comment: I don't see this behavior.

Comment: I see a small square (5px by 5px, at its upper left corner) for the marker with the "rect" shape, the other marker's click area seems to be circular and match the icon.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this problem is happening only on my OS. I tried Chrome, FF and Opera, using incognito as well and the behavior is the same, testing linked JSFiddle every time. If I try it out on different computer or in a VM, the problem disappears.